# Converting to float a list of lists containing strings

Tags: python, string, list

I have this List of lists containing string values:

```
List = [['138.314038', '-35.451642'],
['138.313946', '-35.45212'],
['138.313395', '-35.45291'],
['138.312425', '-35.453978'],
['138.311697', '-35.454879'],
['138.311042', '-35.45569'],
['138.310407', '-35.45647'],
['138.315603', '-35.44981'],
['138.315178', '-35.450241'],
['138.314603', '-35.450948'],
['138.314038', '-35.45164']]
```

I am trying to transform each string value in the list of lists into a float value.

I was trying:

```
results = [float(i) for i in List]
```

But I am only indexing the lists and not the values inside. How can I do it using a similar approach and keeping the same structure of the variable List.

Answer (score 4):

You have list, so use a double comprehension:

```
results = [[float(i) for i in e] for e in List]
```

Answer (score 4):

I am using `numpy` convert it

```
np.array(List).astype(float).tolist()
Out[185]: 
[[138.314038, -35.451642],
 [138.313946, -35.45212],
 [138.313395, -35.45291],
 [138.312425, -35.453978],
 [138.311697, -35.454879],
 [138.311042, -35.45569],
 [138.310407, -35.45647],
 [138.315603, -35.44981],
 [138.315178, -35.450241],
 [138.314603, -35.450948],
 [138.314038, -35.45164]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe ugly using two `list` `map`s:

```
print(list(map(lambda x: list(map(float,x)), List)))
```

Output:

```
[[138.314038, -35.451642], [138.313946, -35.45212], [138.313395, -35.45291], [138.312425, -35.453978], [138.311697, -35.454879], [138.311042, -35.45569], [138.310407, -35.45647], [138.315603, -35.44981], [138.315178, -35.450241], [138.314603, -35.450948], [138.314038, -35.45164]]
```

Print it better:

```
pprint.pprint(list(map(lambda x: list(map(float,x)), List)))
```

Output:

```
[[138.314038, -35.451642],
 [138.313946, -35.45212],
 [138.313395, -35.45291],
 [138.312425, -35.453978],
 [138.311697, -35.454879],
 [138.311042, -35.45569],
 [138.310407, -35.45647],
 [138.315603, -35.44981],
 [138.315178, -35.450241],
 [138.314603, -35.450948],
 [138.314038, -35.45164]]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#you can use map function as well
results = [list(map(float,x)) for x in List]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can expand the list, like this:

```
results = [list(map(float, l)) for l in List]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use map to achieve it.

```
floats = [ list(map(float, i)) for i in List ]
```